# Wocommerce Diferent template for only one product

Tags: woocommerce

I have a simply question :
Can i use different template for just one product leaving default template untouched ?
My case : I have little shop with 4 products but , i want to modify template just for  first product .
Thanks a lot .

Comment: Thanks , cam you show me an example ?  i am very noob

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is totally possible. You can override the single-product.php template from Woocommerce by copying the template in (your-child-theme-root/woocommerce/single-product.php). Then you set a condition using the product id and load the template you created for that specific product. PD: Sorry if my English is not 100%.

Comment: Don't worry for your English  , i understand you . "set a condition using the product id and load the template" This is very crucial for me can you post an example ?